# Managed Stack Explorer for CLR 4

Tags: .net-4.0

Anyone aware of a port of Managed Stack Explorer for .net 4 runtime?

Answer (score 11):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/07/19/clr-stack-explorer-preview.aspx

> CLR Stack Explorer obtains reliable call stacks of managed processes,
>   supports any combination of 32-bit/64-bit and CLR2/CLR4.

[image]

Comment: The link is broken. This answer is no longer useful.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: https://github.com/vadimskipin/MSE

Basically it is simple UI for CorDbg API using wrappers from MDBG sample.
If you really prefer MSE over WinDBG/SOS - you are welcome!

Comment: Link is broken (404) This answer is no longer useful

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives:

[CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1)

[VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx)

[WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)

Answer (score 2):

Here is x64 and x32 version of MSE with support for .NET 4.0. Спасибо Вадим

https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/managed-stack-explorer-with-support-for-net-framework-4-0-x32-and-x64-versions/

Comment: The link is broken. This answer is no longer useful.

Comment: Updated link to newer location

Answer (score 0):

[ProcInsp](https://github.com/CUSTIS-public/ProcInsp) (I'm its developer) is another alternative of MSE. It allows to view [running threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKo66.png) and [stack traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2l4G.png) of clr processes.